# accessing .env variables in vue3 using vite

Tags: vuejs3, laravel-9, .env

I'm trying to pull a key from .env in my vue3 page. I've read the instructions at https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html and I can get VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME using:

```
console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME);
```

The same doesn't work for VITE_STRIPE_KEY, which I assume means that my .env is cached somehow, so that my changes aren't being reflected. I've tried `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` to ensure it's not cached, but I still get undefined for `import.meta.env.VITE_STRIPE_KEY`.

My .env includes:

```
VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
VITE_STRIPE_KEY=stripe_key
```

My vue file has:

```
console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_STRIPE_KEY);
console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME);
```

How can I refresh my .env file properly so that it's accessible in vue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, quitting npm and running `npm run watch` again fixed the problem.